# Change HTML markup structure with jQuery

Tags: jquery

**I have a structure like this:**

```
<div class="row tabs specialtabfontsize"> 
    <nav class="tabsnav">
      <a class="stdhead" href=""> tab1 </a>
      <a class="stdhead" href=""> tab2 </a>
      <a class="stdhead" href=""> tab3 </a>
    </nav>

    <article class="columns">content1...</article>
    <article class="columns">content2...</article>
    <article class="columns">content3...</article> 
</div>
```

**I want to change it to this with jQuery:**

```
<div class="row tabs specialtabfontsize">    
    <nav class="tabsnav"><a class="stdhead" href=""> tab1 </a></nav>
    <article class="columns">content1...</article>

    <nav class="tabsnav"><a class="stdhead" href=""> tab2 </a></nav>
    <article class="columns">content2...</article>

    <nav class="tabsnav"><a class="stdhead" href=""> tab3 </a></nav>
    <article class="columns">content3...</article>

</div>
```

This is meant for a mobile view. In the desktop version, it looks like tabs. But I want to show them like an accordion in the mobile version. I cannot change the markup; so I have to work with the script only.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Logically the next question to any answer might be: "Now how can I undo the changes applied by this code?"

Comment: I am trying with getting the indexes and of the "a", wrap them within "nav" and put them before "article". I am posting my code in updates.

Comment: Can't you accomplish this with CSS?  I thought that was the point of having separate styles for desktop and mobile.  Leave the HTML alone, and style appropriately on each screen size.

Comment: The approach is wrong. Don't alter the DOM

Comment: I could easily do that with CSS. But then I have to change the HTML also, which I can't. I have restriction for editing HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ia a [working solution](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5MUbK/2/).

```
var myNavs = new Array();
var myContents = new Array();
var i=0;

$(".stdhead").each( function () {
    myNavs[i++]=$(this).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
});

i=0;

$(".columns").each( function () {
    myContents[i++]=$(this).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();    
});

$(".specialtabfontsize").empty();
for(j=0;j<i;j++) {
    $(".specialtabfontsize").append('<nav class="tabsnav">' + myNavs[j] + '</nav>' + myContents[j]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. I did a slight change that allows the original "a" and "article" tags to be preserved.

Comment: Even better. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted, this is not the best approach, but if you absolutely have to, you can do it like this:

```
var newHTML = "",
    $row = $('.row'),
    $links = $row.find("a"),
    $articles = $row.find("article");

$links.each(function(i, el){
  newHTML += "<nav class='tabsnav'>" + el.get(0) + "</nav>" + $articles[i].get(0);
});

$(".row").html(newHTML);
```

If you had to revert this, based on window size for example, it would be quite simple.